# Lyrics of "The friends of Mr. Cairo" by Vangelis and Jon Anderson

Tags: lyrics

I was able to find the [lyrics](https://www.vangelislyrics.com/vangelis-lyrics-collaborations/jon-and-vangelis-friends-of-mr-cairo-lyrics.htm#THE%20FRIENDS%20OF%20MR.%20CAIRO) of "The friends of Mr. Cairo":

> ...
> From Chicago to Hong Kong
> Via Istanbul the **Talking Tong**
> ...

I would very much appreciate if someone could tell me what's meant by "Talking Tong".

Comment: The song lyrics are full of references to 30s gangster films. The backstory of the characters in the [Maltese Falcon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Maltese_Falcon_(1941_film))  (referenced in the lyrics) is that they have been in search of the Falcon (a valuable statuette) round the world. when the statuette is found to be a fake, the quest goes on to Istanbul. But I am not sure of the connection to Tong, unless this is a reference to something else from another gangster story

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[A Tong](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tong_(organization)) is a type of organization, described as secret societies (like a Lodge) or sworn brotherhoods and are often tied to criminal activity.

Within the lyrics the tong is one of a number of criminal elements referenced. The "talking tong" is a meaningless phrase to achieve alliteration and rhythm in the song:

> From chicago to hong kong
>   via istanbul the talking tong